# java.lang.SecurityException: The request is coming from a malicious source

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic

I am facing issue with URL accessing...The exception I am getting as mentioned below. I am not able to find proper solution for it. Could anyone can suggest me how can I resolve this issue. Server I am using is Tomcat and Weblogic. Two servers has the similar problem.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: The request is coming from a malicious source.
at com..HeaderFilter.validateJSRequest(HeaderFilter.java:217)
at com..HeaderFilter.doFilter(HeaderFilter.java:146)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3739)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3705)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2282)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2181)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: The request is coming from a malicious source.
at com.SecurityFilter.validateOriginAndRefererHeaders(SecurityFilter.java:491)
at com.HeaderFilter.validateJSRequest(HeaderFilter.java:209)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The request is coming from a malicious source.
at com..SecurityFilter.validateOriginRefererHeaders(SecurityFilter.java:479)
... 12 more
```

[image]

Comment: You cant do anything about it. My guess is that the domain of the URL you are trying to access is identified as infected.

Comment: can we see the ***malicious request***????

Comment: Please see the attached screenshot.

Comment: As part of our application configuration...we are verifying the coming request is matching to the configured url in configuration file. If it is not matching, it starts throwing the above exception. Once, I declare the request URL into the configuration file. It started working properly.